# Why is my icon not being distributed to the device?

Tags: iphone

During the work on my iPhone application the icon changed from time to time. Colleagues or management came with fancy new ideas and .pngS and all I did was changing the Icon.png in the file system. Most times the new icon was distributed to simulator or device with the very next build, sometimes I had to delete and add th icon.png in Xcode (images), but it worked.
Then, the other day I added the UIPrerenderedIcon element to the info.plist to eliminate the icon's shine (it worked) and since I did, I've problems with bringing new icons to the device:

- Simulator shows new icon when in debugging mode
- Simulator doesn't present new icon in release mode (only when debugging was used before)
- Never new icons on any iPhone or iPod
- Whenever icon distribution fails, a white square or (even stranger to me) an old icon (corresponding .png is completly eliminated from the file system) is shown

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cleaning all targets, that is most likely the case of the old icon showing up.

Also, this happened to me a few times (with in app images)...

The simulator is case insensitive to file names, but the device IS case sensitive.

So, if in the info.plist you say your icon file is: ICON.png

But the actual file is named: icon.png

Then, the simulator will display the icon, However, the device will not.

Answer (score 2):

When ever you change the icon image Try deleting the old application from the simulator/iPhone and thenm reinstall it.. Some times such problem occur with me too.. and also
FOR icon on iTunes
Make the icon image 512 x 512 JPEG or PNG file named iTunesArtwork. Then go to get info and remove the extension. Note that the file must not have an extension.

After generating the file of your application’s icon, follow these steps to add it to your application:

1. Open your project in Xcode.
2. In the Groups & Files list, select the Resources group.
3. Choose Project > Add to Project, navigate to your iTunesArtwork file, and click Add.
4. In the dialog that appears, select the ”Copy items” option and click Add.

Note that the PNG or JPEG file is just 'iTunesArtwork', with no suffix.

If you try to copy the file into the application bundle after you have built it, it will break the app signing, and you will get a verification error when trying to sync it to your device. Ensure that the artwork file is included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" folder, within your project's target in XCode (step 4, above).

Then drag and drop your app file to the iTunes for cross checkin whether you have done all things correct or not.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Seems odd that the .xcassets file is not automatically copied to the bundle, when selected for a target, but this is still the ase for XCode 8. Manually adding it to Build Rules/Copy Bundle Resources fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Start Application in xcode
1 Change the name of the icon.png to icon1.png
2 Remove the app from the simulator or the device
3 Clean all targets
4 Change icon1.png back to icon.png
5 Run app again